# PDF view in mobile and Safari browser

Tags: ios, reactjs, pdf

I've developed website using react js and implemented PDF view feature now the scenarios I'm facing like below:

1. in Desktop, all the browsers PDF load successfully
2. in mobile, Chrome PDF gives me Open button
3. in Mobile, Mozilla PDF loads successfully
4. in Safari, PDF loads but showing only 1 page out of 7 pages

I've used `<iframe>` tag to show PDF.

My code is :

```
  <div style={{height: "calc(100vh - 286px)"}}>
    <iframe
      id="myiframe"
      src={pdfUrl}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
    />
  </div>
```

now I want to load and open PDF as per Mozilla showing in mobile view.

Comment: Hey @KJ thank you for the update, your answer will work but I've resolved this with `import { Worker, Viewer, SpecialZoomLevel } from "@react-pdf-viewer/core";` this library, but definitely will try your answer too so I can get idea about another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this using
`import { Worker, Viewer, SpecialZoomLevel } from "@react-pdf-viewer/core";`

```
    <Worker workerUrl={pdfBaseUrl}>
        <Viewer
           fileUrl={pdfUrl}
           pageLayout={pageLayout}
           plugins={[
              pageNavigationPluginInstance,
              thumbnailPluginInstance,
           ]}
           initialPage={0}
           httpHeaders={{mode: "no-cors"}}
           defaultScale={SpecialZoomLevel.PageWidth}
       />
    </Worker>
```